# ngx datatable shift column to the right (add padding)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have made a datatable using row grouping function of ngx datatable. Actually, I would like to shift the first column to the right but I don't know how to do this.
[Image of what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxXm4.png)

this is my html code

```html
<div>
  <ngx-datatable #myTable class="material expandable" [rows]="rows" [groupRowsBy]="'year'"
    [columnMode]="'force'"  [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="60" [limit]="10">
    <ngx-datatable-group-header #myGroupHeader>
      <ng-template let-group="group" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-group-header-template>
        <div class="group-div" style="padding-left:5px;">
          <span [class.datatable-icon-right]="!expanded" [class.datatable-icon-down]="expanded"
            title="Expand/Collapse Group" (click)="toggleExpandGroup(group)">
            <b>{{ 'ASSIGNMENT-CHOOSER.YEAR' | translate }} : {{ group.key }}</b>
          </span>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-group-header>

    <ngx-datatable-column name="id" prop="id"></ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column name="name" prop="title" ></ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column name="course" prop="course" ></ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column name="program" prop="program"></ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column name="year" prop="year"></ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column name="date">
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{ row.lastModificationDate | date: 'short' }}
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
  </ngx-datatable>
</div>
```

function used in my typeScript to toggle groups:

```
toggleExpandGroup(group) {
    this.table.groupHeader.toggleExpandGroup(group);
  }
```

I have seen on different topic on the net that I can use .ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatable-body and .datatable-body-row in a css. But if I do this, I will break my others table that display differently my datas.
If somebody have any idea or solution, instead that create a invisible column, thank you by advanced.